# Mysql delete close duplicates of a field

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-delete

In MySQL, is it possible to delete where a field is equal to another row with a prefix?

For example (psuedo-code):

```
DELETE from `table` WHERE `field` = CONCAT("duplicate-of-", field)
```

Assuming I have have these rows, I'd like to delete all of the corresponding duplicates which have that prefix

```
+ Field                 +
------------------------
| name               |
| duplicate-of-name  |
| name2              |
| duplicate-of-name2 |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `join`:

```
DELETE tdup
    FROM table tdup JOIN
         table t
         ON tdup.field = CONCAT('duplicate-of-', t.field);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this with the `exists` operator:

```
DELETE
FROM   `table` t1
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT *
               FROM   `table` t2
               WHERE  t2.`field` = CONCAT("duplicate-of-", t1.field))
```

Comment: wouldn't this delete the original value instead of the duplicate

Comment: @TheIntegrator arg, true 'dat. I mixed up my aliases. Edited and fixed.